What are the Eclipse Plugin equivalent for these VSCode extension points?
I have a VSCode extension that provides a few useful commands. Broadly, they:

Register a command for the command palette.
When run, record the current file and line selection.
Show an input box to get a quick answer from the user.
Load some user-configurable settings.
Replace the selection recorded in 2 with updated contents.
Show various messages throughout.

These are vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.uri,  vscode.window.activeTextEditor.selection, vscode.window.showInformationMessage, vscode.workspace.getConfiguration, vscode.window.showInputBox, vscode.window.showQuickPick, and vscode.window.activeTextEditor.edit.
What are the Eclipse equivalents to these commands? And generally, what is the best source for Eclipse plugin API documentation?

Can you instead explain what you're trying to do? A 1:1 mapping is unlikely. Have you checked the Snippets View from WTP?

What is the "Snippets View" from WTP?
I'm trying to do exactly what I said in the post - register something in a command palette equivalent, get some information from the current file & config, and edit the file. As for a 1:1 mapping, generally, I'd agree, but these are pretty fundamental API details for an IDE to expose. I'm just not familiar with the Eclipse API surface area.

The most up to date guide and API reference is at https://help.eclipse.org/latest/nav/2 . The Snippets View is one where that the user can drag from and drop into text editors, including prompting for variable placeholders to be filled while dropping. You can find it by searching for "snippets" using https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2024-03 in the Install New Software dialog. I don't think it replaces selected text though, only inserts, because the dropping doesn't care about what's selected.

Hmm. Snippets aren't going to be enough for what I'm trying to do. Thank you for the link to the dev guide- it wasn't coming up on Google searches (only the marketing and download pages).  It's also not very mobile friendly. I'll give it a deeper look.
